# Maven not running scala tests

Tags: maven, scalatest

I have following in pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, made changes as documented [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin).

And test as:

```
class MyTest extends FunSuite {
    test("....") {
        assert(2+2 == 4)
    }
}
```

'mvn clean install' has output as:

> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Maven is not executing the tests. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an answer to your question, but should allow you to run your tests.

You could use `JUnitRunner` and `surefire` to run your tests.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 ...
```

And then annotate your test class with:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyTest extends FunSuite {
```